# Select same values from different schema dynamically based on a common table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a database consisting of mutiple schemas with same structure. This enables to segregate data based on enterprise. So there could be mutiple schemas like db_client1, db_client2 etc. and common properties are defined in public schema. There is one such common table with definition as below:

```
CREATE TABLE enterprises(
    ent_id bigint,
    schema_name character varying
)
```

There is a requirement to pick all similar information from some tables for all schemas. So for each entry in table enterprises I need to select information from corresponding schema_name. The query to be fired for each enterprise is

```
SELECT v1.no, v1.surrogate_id, v2.startdate, v2.enddate  
FROM table1 v1
INNER JOIN table2 v2 on v2.surrogate_id = v1.surrogate_id
```

We would require schema_name to be appended to each table in the above query from table enterprises. How can we get all data for all enterprises without using any cursor. The sample output I am looking for is

```
ent_id    no        surrogate_id         startdate         enddate
100001    1001      2001                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100001    1002      2002                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100001    1003      2003                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100002    1001      4001                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100002    1002      4002                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100003    1001      4001                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100003    1002      4002                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100004    1001      4001                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
100004    1002      4002                 2014-03-01        2014-03-05
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a pl/pgsql stored function (with multiple `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`) for this.

Something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION run_sql_all_enterprises(sql TEXT)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    row public.enterprises%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM public.enterprises LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(sql, row.schema_name);
    END LOOP;
END $function$;
```

And you could call it like

```
SELECT * FROM run_sql_all_enterprises($sql$
    SELECT v1.no, v1.surrogate_id, v2.startdate, v2.enddate  
    FROM %1$I.table1 v1
    INNER JOIN %1$I.table2 v2 on v2.surrogate_id = v1.surrogate_id
$sql$) AS (
    no INT,
    surrogate_id INT,
    startdate DATE,
    enddate DATE
);
```

But, if you do this often (to crawl the same structured data form multiple schemas), i suggest you to re-normalize your structure to use only one schema - with a column in each table where it is suitable & which points to the current row's *enterprise*.

Comment: I have a similar solution but I am against using cursor.